# Android Room: Type mismatch: inferred type is java.util.Observer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am stuck debugging a nasty type error with Android room. I understand that probably somewhere a wrong type is returned but I cannot figure out where.
The error happens in an Activity in the code segment:

```
29    feelingViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FeelingViewModel::class.java)
30    feelingViewModel.allFeelings.observe(this, Observer { feelings ->
31        feelings?.let { adapter.setFeelings(it) }
32    })
```

The error messages I get are

```
30: Type mismatch: inferred type is java.util.Observer but androidx.lifecycle.Observer<in List<Feeling>!> was expected
30: Expected 2 parameters of types Observable!, Any!
31: Type mismatch: inferred type is Observable but List<Feeling> was expected
```

I guess you need more code but I am unsure which parts of the code are needed. So feel free to ask and I will update this question accordingly.

Thanks!

Comment: Change your import, you're supposed to use `androidx.lifecycle.Observer`, not `java.util.Observer`...

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue :)